# Vector Autoregression with Trials

Tags: multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression

I want to use VAR model on my data. In addition to typical two dimensions (variables, time steps), I have a third dimension, namely the repetitions of the same experiment.

Can you recommend a toolbox that can account for this third dimension. I mainly use python, and I have tried StatsModels library, but it does not seem to support this extension.

I have constructed the loss function for this problem myself, and it is very similar to the 2D loss function, so it should be easy to implement. Still, I would like to avoid coding it myself, because that would involve fine-tuning the regularized numerical minimization procedure, which I believe might not be completely trivial and has already been figured out before